# Character collision when hits edges of window

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm having troubles having my character stop once it hits the edges of the windows.
Here's my update method.

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
    {
        Input input = gc.getInput();
        playerX += VelocityX;

        gc.setShowFPS(Splash.showFps);

        if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_F1))
        {
            Splash.showFps = !Splash.showFps;
        }

        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT))
            VelocityX = 10;
        else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT))
            VelocityX = -10;
        else if (playerX >= 700)
            VelocityX = 0;
        else
        {
            VelocityX = 0;
        }

    }
```

I realize going off to left is occurring because I haven't coded it yet but the character goes off the screen the right

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
        VelocityX = 10;}
    else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
        VelocityX = -10;}
    else{VelocityX = 0;}
    if (playerX >699){
        playerX=699;
        VelocityX = 0;}
    else if(playerX<1){
         playerX=1;VelocityX = 0;
         }
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this before and it worked but then the character couldn't move at all once stopping on the edge.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. Within the key detection you set the velocity to 0.

So instead

```
if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT))
            VelocityX = 10;
        else if (playerX >= 700)
            VelocityX = 0;
```

Do something like

```
if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT))
        {
            VelocityX = 10;
            if (playerX >= 700)
                VelocityX = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong I noticed. The first is your update issue: you want to player to move by their velocity. You also need to do your bounds checking. Another problem you have, that others haven't noted on, is that you have a right key preference, That means that if you are holding the right and left key, the player moves right. This is due to the if / else if statements. You should separate your ifs out for a more granular level of control:

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    //playerX += VelocityX; -> this is moved

    gc.setShowFPS(Splash.showFps);

    if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_F1))
    {
        Splash.showFps = !Splash.showFps;
    }

    VelocityX = 0;
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT))
        VelocityX += 10;
    //removed the else
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT))
        VelocityX -= 10;

    //you want to bounds check regardless of the above statments
    //get rid of the else
    if ((playerX >= 700 && VelocityX > 0) || (playerX <= 0 && VelocityX < 0)) //check both sides
        VelocityX = 0;

    //move the player
    playerX += VelocityX;
}
```

EDIT: Modified my code to fix the issue of being unable to move when at a boundary.